# Simple way to degrade Organic Tabs gracefully to work in IE9 high security (aka no js)?

Tags: javascript, drupal, hash, tabs

I know, I should have built this in a progressive enhancement way instead of trying to gracefully degrade. But I didn't. So now I need a way to make this work, preferably without altering the structure too much.

What I need is, if they don't have javascript enabled, then it will reload the page and add a hash tag. Based on that hash tag I wish to load different data into a spot.

I am using Drupal and this is dynamic content and there are hundreds of pages. I can change the markup easily across all of them from the template... it's just a very basic implementation of Organic tabs, but with variables in place of the tab titles and bodies.

Based on my research, I would think this has to be done manually (with separate pages that "look" like tabs), but I know that is not the case as I have seen this functionality here: http://observers.gohernandez.com/election/results/2005/kabul With the quicktabs module.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I can use a get method with PHP but Organic Tabs doesn't pick up the links unless they are #hash links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, after sifting through literally hundreds of tabs plugins, this one that actually degrades gracefully: http://blog.ginader.de/archives/2009/02/07/jQuery-Accessible-Tabs-How-to-make-tabs-REALLY-accessible.php